# CouchDB - MyCouch fieldname is wrong after Transmitting

Tags: c#, couchdb, field, field-names, mycouch

I have a "little" problem with my program here. I am using MyCouch(C# Lib for CouchDB).

I am transmitting a Record(see below) to a local DB. Everything works fine, but the first letter from fieldnames gets lowered all time and messes up the whole program. I MUST use the first letter as higher because of reasons.

Here is the Record Class:

```
    public class Record
{

    public string KartenNummer, StudentID;

    public int ReaderIDKommen, ReaderIDGehen;

    public bool erledigt, gueltig;

    public string Kommen, Gehen;
}
```

Here you can see some of the fieldnames wiht Capped first letter(e.g.: KartenNummer, StudentID)

Here is the transmitting part:

```
        public static async void Transmit(MyCouchClient client, Record record)
    {
        MyCouch.Requests.PostEntityRequest<Record> insert = new MyCouch.Requests.PostEntityRequest<Record>(record);
        MyCouch.Responses.EntityResponse<Record> reponse = await client.Entities.PostAsync(insert);
    }
```

Very simple. But somehow it still changes the first letter... Here you can see the Record in the Database as JSON:

```
{"_id":"9b3db191e92bc8b441d62c8428002bc1","_rev":"1-b734e38ec9996f0ba995c4ebda9a57b3","$doctype":"record","kartenNummer":"1A4E6B08","studentID":"100","readerIDKommen":9999,"readerIDGehen":0,"erledigt":false,"gueltig":false,"kommen":"2016-28-02 15:00:15.015"}
```

Here the KartenNummer is now kartenNummer and StudentID changed to studentID.

Can someone help me? In the docu of mycouch it does not change a thing and the first letter stays capped...
https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#modular

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#entities-and-serialization I hope this helps. Not sure if it's possible to control how the data will be stored if you use their serializer. You'll have to modify it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think i read this Docu 100 times but i never saw that part...
Solved thanks